# How to use an excel cell on an MDX calculated measure?

Tags: excel, mdx

We are using Excel to acces a SSAS Olap cube. We use some calculated measures defined on the excel sheet.

On one of them we need to use a user value entered on a specific cell.

Kind of

```
[Measures].[Sales]*$a$10
```

We cannot find any way to do it. Any idea?

**Edit**:

As it seems we cannot find a solution, we were thinking to create a new table with the valid values (it's a finite short list) and use them as a filter, so we could use the value on the formula.
I cannot imagine how to do that, because it would be a table not related to any other table in the cube ...
Does this make any sense?

**Edit**: solved, see below.

Comment: the value in $a$10 can change?

Comment: Yes, sure! Otherwise I could write the constant value in the formula :)

Answer (score -1):

hahahahahah .... this is probably the craziest idea I had since a long time ... but it works!

We just created an **Excel macro!!** that rebuilds the calculated measure when the specified cell changes:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections( _
    "MyHost MyOLAP MyCube").OLEDBConnection. _
    CalculatedMembers("[Measures].[MyFormula]").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Connections( _
    "MyHost MyOLAP MyCube").OLEDBConnection. _
    CalculatedMembers.AddCalculatedMember Name:="[Measures].[MyFormula]", _
    Formula:=Array("[Measures].[Sales]*" & Range("d1").Value), _
    Type:=xlCalculatedMeasure,SolveOrder:=0, ParentHierarchy:= _
    "[Measures]", NumberFormat:=xlNumberFormatTypeDefault
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivotTable").RefreshTable
```

:) :)